# MS Office Word: How to create a custom minibar to a content control (richtext) in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, word-contentcontrol

I am trying to modify a custom content control I've created. Specifically I want to add a minibar containing one or two buttons to a quick and short modification of the text included in my content control. The image below shows the outcome I want to have - the problem is that these buttons are only shown in built-in table content control and I can't find any useful information on the web about how to create something like that myself... Could you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the commands shown next to the content control title are not customizable; it's definitely something we've thought about, but this isn't possible today.

You could use the ContentControlOnEnter and ContentControlOnExit events to show buttons on the context menu or the ribbon; depending on your scenario, that might work?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already thought about the ribbon or context menu and that's my alternative. However I was hoping that precisely this would be possible. For now I will do as you suggested, but should I leave the quesion unanswered or are you 100% sure that it's something unachievable for today?